# SIGNAL and SLOT between 2 windows QT

Tags: c++, qt, variables

Salam Wa Alikom

Hi Everyone :)

i want to connect to windows using SIGNAL and SLOT so i can pass variable from the first window to the second windows

exactly i want to pass the value of `nom` from the lineEDIT from login.cpp to menu.cpp

i have 2 windows

> login.ui
>   and
>   menu.ui

this is login.h

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtSQl>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDialog>
#include "menu.h"

namespace Ui {
class login;
}

class login : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit login(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~login();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();


private:
    Ui::login *ui;
    Menu *menu;
    QSqlDatabase db;
};

#endif // LOGIN_H
```

login.cpp

```
#include "login.h"
#include "ui_login.h"
#include "QPixmap"
#include "QCryptographicHash"
#include <QDialog>


login::login(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::login)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->horizontalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
            ui->spinBox,SLOT(setValue(int)));

    // logos header
    QPixmap isem_img("C:/Users/Amine/Documents/QT/E-LogBook/resource/img/ISEM.png");
    ui->img_ISEM->setPixmap(isem_img);
    QPixmap mm_img("C:/Users/Amine/Documents/QT/E-LogBook/resource/img/MM.png");
    ui->img_MM->setPixmap(mm_img);

    // Connexion database
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("");
    db.setDatabaseName("journal_machine");

    // ouverture database
    if(db.open())
    {
        ui->label_db_status->setText("Connecté");
    }else{
        ui->label_db_status->setText("Connexion echoué");
    }
}

login::~login()
{
    delete ui;
}

void login::on_pushButton_clicked()
{ menu = new Menu(this);
    menu ->show();
    QString password,nom,password_db;
    nom = ui->lineEdit_nom->text();// get data from input
    password = ui->lineEdit_password->text();// get data from input

    if (password == NULL || nom == NULL){ // si les cases sont vides
        ui->label_etat->setText("Champ non rempli");
    } else
    {
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.exec("SELECT * FROM `equipage` WHERE Nom='"+nom+"'");// Query
        if (query.next() == true) {
        password_db = query.value(2).toString(); // get value from mysql
        QString password_md5 = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash((password.toUtf8()),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());// cryptage du password
        if (password_md5 == password_db) {// si le mot de pass est correct


        //  this->hide();
        } else {
            // si le mot de pass est faux
        }
        }
        query.finish();
    }
}
```

and menu.h

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class Menu;
}

class Menu : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Menu(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Menu();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Menu *ui;
};

#endif // MENU_H
```

menu.cpp

```
#include "menu.h"
#include "ui_menu.h"
#include "login.h"

Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Menu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


}
Menu::~Menu()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

finaly main.cpp

```
#include "login.h"
#include "menu.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    login w;
    Menu z;
    w.show();
    z.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Thanks in advance
Chokran :)

Comment: obviously you need write `connect` to connect signal and slot, what is your question?

Comment: i don't know how to do it ^^

Comment: In your code there is call of `connect` how can you write it if you don't know how to do it?

Comment: it's in the same window i want to connect 2 different windows ^^

Comment: `connect` method is member function of `QObject`, windows, line edit, slider, spin box all actually inherits `QObject`, you already create connection in your code between two qobjects, at now you need create connection between another two qobjects just write `connect(window1, SIGNAL(), window2, SLOT());`, what is the problem?

Comment: what should i put exactly ??
`connect(login,SIGNAL(),menu,SLOT())`
and where should i write it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In login.h create a signal to send the nom value.

## login.h

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtSQl>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDialog>
#include "menu.h"

namespace Ui {
class login;
}

class login : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit login(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~login();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

signals:                                    // <-------
    void loginButtonClicked(int nomVal);  // <-------

private:
    Ui::login *ui;
    Menu *menu;
    QSqlDatabase db;
};
```

In menu class create the slot that you want to be executed from login signal and variable to store nom value.

## menu.h

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class Menu;
}

class Menu : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Menu(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Menu();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();
    void loginButtonClicked(int nomVal);  //<-----------

private:
    Ui::Menu *ui;
    int nomValue;                //<-----------
};

#endif // MENU_H
```

## menu.cpp

```
#include "menu.h"
#include "ui_menu.h"
#include "login.h"

Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Menu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


}

void Menu::loginButtonClicked(int nomVal)
{
      nomValue = nomVal;
}

Menu::~Menu()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

In login.cpp connect the signal to the slot and emit the signal.

## login.cpp

```
#include "ui_login.h"
#include "QPixmap"
#include "QCryptographicHash"
#include <QDialog>


login::login(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::login)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->horizontalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
            ui->spinBox,SLOT(setValue(int)));

    // logos header
    QPixmap isem_img("C:/Users/Amine/Documents/QT/E-LogBook/resource/img/ISEM.png");
    ui->img_ISEM->setPixmap(isem_img);
    QPixmap mm_img("C:/Users/Amine/Documents/QT/E-LogBook/resource/img/MM.png");
    ui->img_MM->setPixmap(mm_img);

    // Connexion database
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("");
    db.setDatabaseName("journal_machine");

    // ouverture database
    if(db.open())
    {
        ui->label_db_status->setText("Connecté");
    }else{
        ui->label_db_status->setText("Connexion echoué");
    }

    connect(this,SIGNAL(loginButtonClicked(int)),menu,SLOT(loginButtonClicked(int)));     //<-------
}

login::~login()
{
    delete ui;
}

void login::on_pushButton_clicked()
{ menu = new Menu(this);
    menu ->show();
    QString password,nom,password_db;
    nom = ui->lineEdit_nom->text();// get data from input
    emit loginButtonClicked(nom);        //<--------
    password = ui->lineEdit_password->text();// get data from input

    if (password == NULL || nom == NULL){ // si les cases sont vides
        ui->label_etat->setText("Champ non rempli");
    } else
    {
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.exec("SELECT * FROM `equipage` WHERE Nom='"+nom+"'");// Query
        if (query.next() == true) {
        password_db = query.value(2).toString(); // get value from mysql
        QString password_md5 = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash((password.toUtf8()),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());// cryptage du password
        if (password_md5 == password_db) {// si le mot de pass est correct


        //  this->hide();
        } else {
            // si le mot de pass est faux
        }
        }
        query.finish();
    }
}
```

So what is going to happen is whenever you push the button on login window, a signal is going to be emitted. That signal is connected to a slot in the menu window, and it will carry nom value to that slot. The connection was made to the menu window that was declared in login window.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to understand first what SIGNAL and SLOTS are.

`connect()` methods works in manner like when particular SIGNAL is emmited the respective SLOT is been called.

Syntax:

`QObject::connect(const QObject * sender, const char * signal, const QObject * receiver, const char * method, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)`

Example:

`connect(yourobj,SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)),this,SLOT(your method/function));`

While using the `connect()` when you enter `SIGNAL()` the Qt editor will automatically show the signals related to your object also when you enter the `SLOT()` it will show methods available within your class.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your time,  i don't know How to connect between the 2 Windows